# Is there a tool I can use to test if an email from china is being blocked?

Tags: dns, email

I'm having problems receiving an email from china, and I think it might be because the email was blocked somehow. Since I am not based in China and do not have access to any computers in China, I can't test this myself. Is there a web service or tool (that's preferable free) I can use to send a test email to an email address to see if it is received or blocked by the Great Firewall of China?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it webmail for your website you are trying to access?  The first step might be to try this test -> http://www.websitepulse.com/help/testtools.china-test.html

Should tell you if your site is blocked or not.

If it is googlemail or some other mailing service you might want to contact them directly.

Comment: Results from the test say there is no response from China for the domain. Since the domain doesn't resolve I guess the email won't resolve either.

Any idea why a domain might be blocked? The domain is only used for email - no website so I can't understand why it is blocked.